# First column of multicol lower than the rest

Tags: spacing, equations, multicol

Using the multicol package, I get a layout like this:
I would like all columns to be aligned properly. I have tried using tables and arrays, but they won't allow my equations to be numbered. (I need to be able to reference them later)

[image: The Problem]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
F_{net} = m_0 a_{net}
\end{equation}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\[F_x = m_0 a_x\]
\[a_x = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_x}{m_0} = 0\]
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = 0
\end{equation}
\[F_y=m_0 a_y\]
\[a_y = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_y}{m_0} = -g\]
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -g
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
These two second order differential equations can be split into four first order differential equations.
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_y}{\mathrm{d}t} = -g
\end{equation}
\end{multicols}
```

## SOLUTION

I wanted to post this for others, if you `\usepackage{amsmath}`, the `align` environment provides a much more elegant solution.

The two second-order differential equations shown in `\vref{eq:2nd-comp}` can be split into four co-dependent first-order differential equations. This is done in order to write the equations in finite difference form.

```
\begin{align}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_x & &\frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0 & &\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_y &                         &\frac{\mathrm{d}v_y}{\mathrm{d}t} = -g
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLUTION

I wanted to post this for others, if you `\usepackage{amsmath}`, the `align` environment provides a much more elegant solution.

```
\begin{align}
 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}   &= v_x & 
 \frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= 0 & 
 \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}   &= v_y & 
 \frac{\mathrm{d}v_y}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -g
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the wisdom of using `multicols` environment to achieve this effect.  Nevertheless, just add some line breaks between the equations, as here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}%% env-> \begin{multicols}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
F_{net} = m_0 a_{net}
\end{equation}
\begin{multicols}{2}

  \[F_x = m_0 a_x\]

  \[a_x = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_x}{m_0} = 0\]

  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = 0
  \end{equation}

  \[F_y=m_0 a_y\]

  \[a_y = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_y}{m_0} = -g\]

  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -g
  \end{equation}

\end{multicols}
These two second order differential equations can be split into four first order differential equations.
\begin{multicols}{4}
  %\abovedisplayskip0pt
  %\abovedisplayshortskip0pt

  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_x
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_y
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}v_y}{\mathrm{d}t} = -g
  \end{equation}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the line breaks, LaTeX thinks those equations are all embedded in the same paragraph.  So the spacing is different above those in the middle of a paragraph as compared with the leading equation, which is seen as starting its own paragraph.

Incidentally, the two commented out lines for `\abovedisplayskip` and `\abovedisplayshortskip` can be useful for tweaking spacing issues too.  But they are not necessary in this context.

Instead of using the `multicols` environment, you could use the `aligned` environment (you'll need to load the `amsmath` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
F_{net} = m_0 a_{net}
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  \notag
  F_x &= m_0 a_x &
  F_y &=m_0 a_y \\[3ex]
  %%
  \notag
  a_x = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= \frac{F_x}{m_0} = 0 &
  a_y = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= \frac{F_y}{m_0} = -g \\[3ex]
  %%
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= 0 &
  \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} &= -g
\end{align}
These two second order differential equations can be split into four first order differential equations.
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}   &= v_x  &
  \frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} &= 0    &
  \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}   &= v_y  &
  \frac{\mathrm{d}v_y}{\mathrm{d}t} &= -g   
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minipage` environment in multicolumn. It follow that:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\[F_x = m_0 a_x\]
\[a_x = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_x}{m_0} = 0\]
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = 0
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\[F_y=m_0 a_y\]
\[a_y = \frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = \frac{F_y}{m_0} = -g\]
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = -g
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
These two second order differential equations can be split into four first order    
differential equations.
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_x
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_x}{\mathrm{d}t} = 0
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.8\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} = v_y
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}v_y}{\mathrm{d}t} = -g
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
```